# AngularJS orderBy - Multiple fields, but only one reversed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-filters, angularjs-orderby

I'm trying to filter based on two variables, the score and the name (score first, then name).

This is for a variety of games, which include games where the score may be in the reverse order (e.g. golf) and games where the scoring is normal (e.g. football).

The code I currently have is:

```
<span ng-repeat="sel in pot.sels | orderBy:['score','name']:CompCtrl.isReverse()">
```

The issue here is that the name is also reversed if the score needs to be. I'm trying to get it so that the **name** is never reversed by the boolean value, but **score** is (**isReverse()** checks if the game is a reverse score game).

Reading through everything I can find, this doesn't seem possible without creating a custom filter to handle this. Is this correct or am I missing a way to do this?

Best way to think about this is, in simple terms, I need the following:

> **Boolean = true** --> -score, name
>
> **Boolean = false** --> score, name

Thanks.

Comment: The [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) documentation has an excellent example on this. You might want to take a look at it.

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm not sure where in the documentation this is? The final example only orders on one field at a time, I'm trying to order on two at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a custom function filter, like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="sel in pot.sels | orderBy:[orderScore,'name']">
```

Where the js is something like this:

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.orderScore = function(el){
        return (isReverse() ? '-' : '+') + el.score;
    }
}]);
```

I didn't tested this, but is to show you the idea, I need only to find a way to return something that can be ordered with <, === and >

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I understand what you're trying to do so will modify the code and see what I can come up with. The solution you posted orders 0's, then 1's, then 2's, etc. The result is a list such as: 0,0,0,1,11,13,2,23,3,4,45,54,....

Comment: Updating my first post, in reverse it ends up as -10, -14, -15, -2, -4, -6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 13, 4, 6

Comment: Easy enough fix, replace the return with `vm.isReverse() ? el.score * -1 : el.score * 1`

Comment: Marked as the answer because I was unaware of how to pass the **sel** into a function defined in the **orderBy** variables (this is where the **el** part comes in). That, plus the custom code, pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: glad to have been helpful to you ;)